# How can I get a TensorFlow C binding for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, c, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

We have a language binding with FFI using the ["TensorFlow for C"](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) and [“the corresponding header files](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h).

While we could find binaries for:

- Linux, 64-bit, x86
- macOS X, Version 10.12.6 (Sierra) or higher
- Windows, 64-bit x86

We can't find binaries for Raspberry/ARM/Raspbian. And this is really a pity because if you go to [Tensorflow downloads](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) you can read that "Raspbian 9.0 or later" is officially supported.

But I need the C binding for Raspberry Pi.

Any idea if the binary is available? and if not, at least instructions for compiling in?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a long search, I found no binary available, so I had to manage myself.
I finally took the time to [write down everything I found during my attempt to get TensorFlow C library compiled for Raspberry Pi](https://dev.to/martinezpeck/challenge-accepted-build-tensorflow-c-binding-for-raspberry-pi-in-2019-4f89). So, feel free to read that for a more detailed answer to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

The last paragraph of the "[TensorFlow for C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c)" you cited points to a [how-to](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/README.md) file which does show you how to build TensorFlow C API from source code with `bazel`

Comment: Thanks @freedom. I didn't know if something special compilation was needed for ARM. Are you aware of people/projects compiling it and using successfully?